# Problems while Styling a form element that gets data back with ajax

Tags: css, jquery

im facing a strange problem while trying to style a form element. A select element in particular.

the idea is simple. i got one select, and when its state changes, through ajax, a second selects gets its data throung a request. so far, everything is ok. the ajax is working fine. but when the first select changes its state, the select element styling is getting back to normal styling.

a live example can be found [here](http://www.creative-artworks.eu/development/cry-for-help/)

im using 2 main files, the important content of file 1 file is this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    /* FUNCTION : Ajax Initialize - Start */
        function getXMLHTTP() {
                var xmlhttp=false;  
                try{
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch(e)    {       
                    try{            
                        xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        try{
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch(e1){
                            xmlhttp=false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return xmlhttp;
            }
    /* FUNCTION : Ajax Initialize - End */


    /* FUNCTION : Get Values - Start */
        function getValue(numb) {       

            var strURL="find.php?theValue="+numb;
            var req = getXMLHTTP();

            if (req) {

                req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (req.readyState == 4) {
                        // only if "OK"
                        if (req.status == 200) {                        
                            document.getElementById('my_requestDiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                        
                        } else {
                            alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                        }
                    }               
                }           
                req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                req.send(null);
            }       
        }
    /* FUNCTION : Get Values - End */

</script>
```

and

```
    <form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="example">

        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="160" class="title_style">What</td>
            <td width="340">
                <select class="select" name="start" onChange="getValue(this.value)">
                    <option value="">please make a selection</option>
                    <option value="1">Colors</option>
                </select>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td width="160" class="title_style">Result</td>
            <td width="340">
              <div id="my_requestDiv">
                <select class="select1" name="my_request" >
                    <option>Please select above first</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

where, after the user makes a selection on select element 1, through ajax, a variable is passed to find.php

```
<?php

    $what=intval($_GET['theValue']);

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'YOUR_USERNAME_HERE', 'YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $link);

    mysql_select_db('cry-for-help');

    $query="SELECT id, value FROM my_table WHERE requested='$what'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

?>

<select class="select" name="my_request">
    <option>make your selection now</option>
        <?php
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
                <option value=<?php echo $row['id']?>><?php echo $row['value']?></option>
        <?php
            }
?>
</select>
```

and the result is posted back on file 1 as content for the second select element.

The Problem is that the styling is gone.

you can download the example files [here](http://www.creative-artworks.eu/development/cry-for-help/cry-for-help.zip)

any help would be appreciated. Also, im sorry if my english is not that good, and my programming skills not that advanced to explain my problem with less words.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Based on the page to which you linked, it looks the problem is that you are replacing all of the extra HTML elements which have been generated by jqtransform. In your JavaScript callback, you are doing this:

```
 document.getElementById('my_requestDiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
```

This replaces the entire contents of the div, blowing away all of the extra elements that jqtransform puts in there. What you actually want to do is replace just the select element itself with the results from your PHP service, or perhaps run jqtransform again after updating the div.

Since you're already including jQuery, I would recommend using their powerful selection functionality to replace just the select element:

```
$('select[name="my_request"]').replaceWith(req.responseText);
```

I'm not familiar with the jqtransform library so you may need to investigate further to see which route makes the most sense.

Comment: thank you for your reply and your effort. would it be possible to point out an example ?? it would really help and guide me where to look. I know google is our friend, but to be honest had no luck at all.

Comment: An example of what, specifically? If you mean an example of how to replace just the select, I've included a jQuery-based one in my answer but I can certainly come up with a plain-old-JavaScript one instead if you'd prefer. If you mean an example of the markup generated by jqtransform, just do a View Source on that example page you linked to. If you mean an example of how to use jqtransform, I can't help you there.

Comment: jmmcduffie, sorry if u got me wrong. i found a way to do that with jQuery, but to be honest, this doesn't work at all. i mean, either the javascript or the jQuery function work fine (i mean with the replace), seems that the problem is jqtransform.

Comment: it seems i have to find another way to style the whole SELECT and hopefully the replace will work. im looking for another plugin/way/workaround to manage the styling, but so far, all solutions i found, didnt work...